# Controlling when Intel TurboBoost kicks in

Tags: windows, cpu, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

With an Intel i7-8650U, is it possible to limit when TurboBoost speeds up the CPU?

I run some virtual soundcard software which requires frequent usage of the CPU.  This causes TurboBoost to kick-in, with XTU reporting my CPU running at 3.8 GHz at all times, yet with 2-3% load.

Eventually, this causes power limiting and severe throttling.  While I've found I can outright disable TurboBoost, and [control its maximum clock rate](https://superuser.com/q/1512924/48624), it would be nice to raise the threshold at which TurboBoost becomes active.  That way, I can still have a faster CPU when I need it, but keep the power usage low (preventing limiting) when it's just the background soundcard driver running.

Is this possible through some configuration, or perhaps other software like ThrottleStop?

I'm running Windows 10 x64.

Comment: As far as I know you can only disable it>>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/intel-turbo-boost-technology-max

Comment: Also See this from Intel>>>>>https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007359/processors/intel-core-processors.html

Comment: Well maybe you can regulate it>>>>>>>>https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/47qczd/how_to_disable_intel_turbo_boost_to_improve/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting max CPU clock rate while in Turboboost](https://superuser.com/questions/1512924/setting-max-cpu-clock-rate-while-in-turboboost)

Comment: Thanks @Moab.  The Windows power settings (as mentioned in the third link you sent) don't have any visible effect.  Even at the lower settings, TurboBoost still locks on.  Also, my previous question you linked to is what prompted me to write this one.  Thanks to the advice in the comments there, I know that I can throttle the TurboBoost.  This is useful, but what I'd really like is to configure the threshold at which TurboBoost is enabled.